# How to fix screen displaying blank after build in electron builder vue 3 in window?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuejs3, electron-builder

I have googled a lot, checked StackOverflow and done changes but after npm run electron:build I am  still facing an issue of blank screen in window. Can anyone help me, please? I would really appreciate it.

```
"vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1"
```

Here is my code.

background.js

```
let win;
async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION
    },
    
  })
  win.maximize();
  win.on("Amir Travel Agency", (event) => event.preventDefault());

  
  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}
```

router.js

```
import {createWebHistory, createRouter, createWebHashHistory} from 'vue-router';
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue';


const router = createRouter({

  history:  process.env.IS_ELECTRON ? createWebHashHistory() : createWebHistory(),
        {
          path:'/',
          name:'home',
          component:Home
        },

}
```